# Como posicionar um slider com position absolute

Tags: html, css, posicionamento, slider

Queria colocar o slider abaixo do título da section, mas como ele está com position absolute, ele não aceita. A não ser que eu use as funções top, bottom, left e right, mas queria saber se há outra forma. E as setas do slider não estão absolutas, então se eu movo as imagens do slider com o top, a seta não se move junto.

```js
const slider = window.document.querySelectorAll('.slider')
const button_prev = window.document.querySelector('.prev-button')
const button_next = window.document.querySelector('.next-button')

let currentSlider = 0

function next_image(){
    if (currentSlider < 5){
        currentSlider++
        slider[currentSlider].classList.add('on')
        slider[currentSlider-1].classList.remove('on')
    }else if (currentSlider == 5){
        currentSlider = 0
        slider[currentSlider].classList.add('on')
        slider[5].classList.remove('on')
    }
}

function prev_image(){
    if (currentSlider > 0){
        currentSlider--
        slider[currentSlider].classList.add('on')
        slider[currentSlider+1].classList.remove('on')
    }else if (currentSlider == 0){
        currentSlider = 5
        slider[currentSlider].classList.add('on')
        slider[0].classList.remove('on')
    }
}
```

```css
.container-images button img{
    width: 100px;
}

.container-images{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.container-slider{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.slider{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.on{
    opacity: 1;
}

.prev-button, .next-button{
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.prev-button img, .next-button img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.slider > img{
    width: 800px;
    height: 550px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -20px 20px 38px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.13);
    -moz-box-shadow: -20px 20px 38px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.13);
    box-shadow: -7px 4px 43px 7px rgb(0 0 0 / 13%);
}
```

```html
<section class="projetos-container" id="projetos">
        <h1 class="projetos-titulo" data-anime="top">projetos</h1>

        <div class="container-slider" data-anime="left">
            
            <button class="prev-button" onclick="prev_image()"><img src="images/play-solid.svg"     alt="Anterior" style="transform: rotate(180deg);"></button>

            <div class="container-images">
                <div class="slider on">
                    <img src="images/bikcraft.png" alt="Projeto Bikcraft">
                    <div class="card-container-principal">
                        <div class="card-topo-principal">
                            <span>Outubro 2022</span>
                            <img src="images/circulos.svg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <h1 class="card-titulo-principal">Projeto de site Bikecraft</h1>
                        <p class="card-texto-principal">Projeto de site feito por mim junto ao curso Origamid. Tem como tema um e-commerce de bicicletas. Seu objetivo é apresentar a loja, seus produtos e seus contatos.
                        </p>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="card-rodape-principal">
                                <span>Acesse o projeto!</span>
                                <img src="images/Arrow.svg" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="slider">
                    <img src="images/portfolio-aleat.png" alt="Projeto Bikcraft">
                    <div class="card-container-principal">
                        <div class="card-topo-principal">
                            <span>Outubro 2022</span>
                            <img src="images/circulos.svg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <h1 class="card-titulo-principal">Projeto de site Bikecraft</h1>
                        <p class="card-texto-principal">Projeto de site feito por mim junto ao curso Origamid. Tem como tema um e-commerce de bicicletas. Seu objetivo é apresentar a loja, seus produtos e seus contatos.
                        </p>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="card-rodape-principal">
                                <span>Acesse o projeto!</span>
                                <img src="images/Arrow.svg" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="slider">
                    <img src="images/site-viagens.png" alt="Projeto Bikcraft">
                    <div class="card-container-principal">
                        <div class="card-topo-principal">
                            <span>Outubro 2022</span>
                            <img src="images/circulos.svg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <h1 class="card-titulo-principal">Projeto de site Bikecraft</h1>
                        <p class="card-texto-principal">Projeto de site feito por mim junto ao curso Origamid. Tem como tema um e-commerce de bicicletas. Seu objetivo é apresentar a loja, seus produtos e seus contatos.
                        </p>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="card-rodape-principal">
                                <span>Acesse o projeto!</span>
                                <img src="images/Arrow.svg" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="slider">
                    <img src="images/site-redes.png" alt="Projeto Bikcraft">
                    <div class="card-container-principal">
                        <div class="card-topo-principal">
                            <span>Outubro 2022</span>
                            <img src="images/circulos.svg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <h1 class="card-titulo-principal">Projeto de site Bikecraft</h1>
                        <p class="card-texto-principal">Projeto de site feito por mim junto ao curso Origamid. Tem como tema um e-commerce de bicicletas. Seu objetivo é apresentar a loja, seus produtos e seus contatos.
                        </p>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="card-rodape-principal">
                                <span>Acesse o projeto!</span>
                                <img src="images/Arrow.svg" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="slider">
                    <img src="images/gauss.png" alt="Projeto Bikcraft">
                    <div class="card-container-principal">
                        <div class="card-topo-principal">
                            <span>Outubro 2022</span>
                            <img src="images/circulos.svg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <h1 class="card-titulo-principal">Projeto de site Bikecraft</h1>
                        <p class="card-texto-principal">Projeto de site feito por mim junto ao curso Origamid. Tem como tema um e-commerce de bicicletas. Seu objetivo é apresentar a loja, seus produtos e seus contatos.
                        </p>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="card-rodape-principal">
                                <span>Acesse o projeto!</span>
                                <img src="images/Arrow.svg" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="slider">
                    <img src="images/wildbeast.png" alt="Projeto Bikcraft">
                    <div class="card-container-principal">
                        <div class="card-topo-principal">
                            <span>Outubro 2022</span>
                            <img src="images/circulos.svg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <h1 class="card-titulo-principal">Projeto de site Bikecraft</h1>
                        <p class="card-texto-principal">Projeto de site feito por mim junto ao curso Origamid. Tem como tema um e-commerce de bicicletas. Seu objetivo é apresentar a loja, seus produtos e seus contatos.
                        </p>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="card-rodape-principal">
                                <span>Acesse o projeto!</span>
                                <img src="images/Arrow.svg" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <button class="next-button" onclick="next_image()"><img src="images/play-solid.svg" alt="Próximo"></button>

        </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

Basta aplicar uma margem no container-slider.

```
margin-top: 300px;
```